# Как отредактировать настройки сети в Centos

Tags: linux, unix, centos, сеть, ifconfig

`ifconfig` показывает два сетевых интерфейса - `eth0` и `eth1`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`ifconfig eth1 down` успешно работает, однако я не знаю где редактировать настройки самой сети. В `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` нет `ifconfig-eth1`. Не понятно даже почему эта сеть получила dhcp, точнее откуда узнала о том что надо получать адрес через `dhcp` -настроек ведь нет.

update

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите `ip addr show`, `ls -lh /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*`, а так же `cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`.

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: вот и редактируйте файлы `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-интерфейс`. https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html

Comment: ну так у меня нет там ifcfg-eth1

Comment: 1. а слово `eth1` в каталоге `/etc/sysconfig` упоминается? см. вывод `$ grep -rl eth1 /etc/sysconfig/` 2. текстовую информацию лучше предоставлять в виде текста, а не картинки: и читать удобнее, и поисковики её проиндексируют

Comment: @Radzhab: а что в файле ifcfg-ens32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS ответвление RHL как и Fedora Linux. Сам являюсь поклонником Fedora, хотяна работе все Debian/Ubntu сторонники.

Приведу вольный перевод со страницы документации о настройке сети в
Fedora. Структура файлов и инструментов будет схожей на CentOS.

**Файлы конфигурации сети**

Прежде чем начать настройку ознакомитесь со основными конфигурационными файлами

**/etc/hosts**

Основная цель - это трансляция имен хостов.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 MyFedoraWorstation
```

**/etc/resolv.conf**

Файл содержит адреса DNS серверов и поисковых доменов

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

**/etc/sysconfig/network**

Файл содержит маршруты и хосты для всех интерфейсов.

**/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-|interface-name|**

Конфигурационная информация для каждого интерфейса известного системе.

Читайте описание параметров в документации, тут приведу пример отвечающего за
"тип" подлючения

```
BOOTPROTO=none|dhcp|static
```

Посмотреть какие интерфейсы определенны системой можно так:

```
~# ls /sys/class/net/
enp2s0  lo  virbr0  virbr0-nic
```

Спасает при составление скриптов, что бы не городить фильтры выхлопов **ip** и
**ifconfig**.

**Примеры конфигурации**

Статичный IP

```
DEVICE=enp2s0
BOOTPROTO=static
HWADDR=00:05:29:E0:4F:3D
IPADDR=10.0.1.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=10.0.1.1
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
```

DHCP клиент

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
HWADDR=00:05:29:E0:4F:3D
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
```

**Ссылки**

- https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/23/pdf/Networking_Guide/Fedora-23-Networking_Guide-en-US.pdf
- https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Network_Interfaces.html
- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html